# using registry to run a prog at startup

Tags: windows, registry

i am trying to run a code in c++ which will result in an .exe file running at startup using registry...but the problem is that the code results fails without showing any errors...i compiled the code in devcpp...
the code is

```
void createkey(char *path)
{
int reg;
HKEY hkey,Hkey1;
DWORD ptr;

reg=RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),0,KEY_SET_VALUE,&hkey);

if(reg=ERROR_SUCCESS)  
   cout<<"success"<<endl;
else 
   cout<<"failure"; //(a)

cout<<reg<<endl;  //(b)

if(reg==0)
{
    RegSetValueEx(hkey,TEXT("key"),0,REG_SZ,(BYTE*)path,strlen(path));
}
}
```

in the command line failure and 0 got printed as a result of (a) and (b)...(dont know how as the two mean completely opposite things )....the char *path passed to regsetvalueex was "c:/Dev-Cpp/bin/Untitled2.exe"...i am sure that the functions are not working as key doesnt appear in run key(i checked using regedit)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(reg=ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

That's an assignment, you need to use the == operator.  Most modern compilers warn about this, be sure to update yours.  You probably got an access denied error, can't write to HKLM\Software without elevation.

Comment: @hans...that was a stupid error i commited..but still my setvalue function fails...did u mean this when u told that this process needs to be run elevated?...also how can i configure devcpp to output maximum warnings....?

Comment: The final parameter to RegSetValueEx is also wrong. And your path slashes are leaning the wrong way. And make sure your customers understand that you are slowing down their boot times for this feature and give them a way to disable it.

Comment: @hans...how can i configure devcpp to output maximum warnings(i.e. how to implement -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic)....?

Comment: @raymond...was there any error other than that the last parameter should be strlen(path)+1....

Comment: @hans...i fixed the errors and ran the program in mvc 2010..but it showed this error...LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\AVINASH KUMAR\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\untitle\Debug\untitled2.exe'....can u help?...i changed the path in my program to this .exe file

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask questions at SO.  Start a new question, after making sure it wasn't already asked of course.

Comment: @hans...i have asked the question...[the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392773/linker-error-in-microsoft-visual-c-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Standard users don't have write access to HKLM. You need to run this process elevated.